# Running Python from PHP

Tags: php, python, caching, egg

I have a python script that runs as a daemon process. I want to be able to stop and start the process via a web page. I made a PHP script that runs exec() on the python daemon. Any idea?

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/app/public_html/daemon/daemon.py", line 6, in      from
>   socketServer import ExternalSocketServer, InternalSocketServer   File
>   "/home/app/public_html/daemon/socketServer.py", line 3, in 
>   import json, asyncore, socket, MySQLdb, hashlib, urllib, urllib2,
>   logging, traceback, sys   File
>   "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/MySQLdb/**init**.py", line 19, in
>      File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/_mysql.py", line 7, in
>      File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/_mysql.py", line 4, in
>   **bootstrap**   File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 882, in resource_filename   File
>   "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1351, in
>   get_resource_filename   File
>   "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1373, in
>   _extract_resource   File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 962, in
>   get_cache_path   File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/pkg_resources.py",
>   line 928, in extraction_error pkg_resources.ExtractionError: Can't
>   extract file(s) to egg cache  The following error occurred while
>   trying to extract file(s) to the Python egg cache:    [Errno 13]
>   Permission denied: '//.python-eggs'  The Python egg cache directory is
>   currently set to:    //.python-eggs  Perhaps your account does not
>   have write access to this directory?  You can change the cache
>   directory by setting the PYTHON_EGG_CACHE environment variable to
>   point to an accessible directory.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure whatever user php is running under has appropriate permissions. You can try opening a pipe and changing users, or just use apache's suexec.